# How to schedule a JSP Page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have a **JSP** page as `task.jsp`. So I want to display this page only once in a year i.e. in the month of March every year.

I dont have any idea how to schedule it. Please help me. Following is my sample controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "task.htm",
    method = RequestMethod.GET
)

public ModelAndView taskPost(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("task");
    //do something
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a [ResponseStatusException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "task.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView taskPost(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task,HttpServletRequest request {
    if(LocalDate.now().getMonth() != Month.MARCH) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Unable to find resource");
    }

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("task");
    //do something
    return model;
}
```

See more:

- [ResponseStatusException (javadoc)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception